# Giving boons or blessings reduce merit?

Tags: curse, boon

Cursing someone reduces the merits of the penances done (by the person who cursed). Does the opposite of this-giving boon or blessing someone-reduce our energy/merit accumulated through penances?

Comment: yes. tapasya = bank balance. both boons and curses use that balance to effect extra-ordinary incidents. e.g. vishvamitra used both curses (on rambha) and boons (on trishanku) that reduced his tapasya, so he had to do 1000 more years of penance each time

Comment: Is it just boons or blessings as well? For example, a Brahmana blessed someone fire long life; dues Brahmana lose a portion of his merits? If it impacts one's savings how anyone keeping any balance these days where people wish others every day for everything!

Comment: boon and blessings are synonymous. Also, you can write a check without having bank balance, right ? Similarly, just wishing/blessing is not enough to make it come true. You need to have enough tapasya in the bank for Bhagavan to fructify your boon/curse.

Comment: Simply said both curses and boons require an amount of tapasya. If you do not have enough tapasya nothing will happen.

Comment: @mar post that as an answer. Baal Khanda of Shrimad  Ramayana covers that part. If you need help with exact verses, let me know.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, yes lmk verses

Comment: Giving blessings does not impact ones merits but infact add more to the eixisting ones, what get's impacted is the energy levels. Human beings like all other beings in the universe encompasses postive and negative energies, giving blessings or cursing are like tapping into these energies that needs to be gained back. With boons, in a similar way it's like inventory how many boons could one give and how much could they give and would they be able to regain to give boon again. You see in bot cases it doesn’t impact the merit, however the merit is impacted on how boons are given and used

Comment: @mar Sorry for the delay. We don't touch holy books without pooja. Today after evening pooja, I managed to take screenshots. Anyway Check verse 16: https://imgur.com/a/nnh3cA3